# Zend_Date::toString() outputs the wrong year. Bug in my code, or Zend_Date?

Tags: zend-framework, zend-date

I'm using `Zend_Date` to set and get the year, but it is not being set as the correct year. I set the year as 2010, and it returns the year as 2009. What am I doing wrong? Is there a bug in `Zend_Date`?

```
$date = new Zend_Date('2010-01-03', 'YYYY-MM-dd');
echo $date->toString('MMMM d, YYYY');
//outputs January 3, 2009
```

The year must be being set correctly because getting the year part of the date works:

```
echo $date->get(Zend_Date::YEAR); //2010
```

### Solution:

Well I got it to work...You have you use lowercase: `yyyy`

```
echo $date->toString('MMMM d, yyyy');
```

- `YYYY` stands for the [ISO Year](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date). 2010-01-03 is week 53, day 7 of the ISO year 2009
- `yyyy` stands for the actual calendar year.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I've ran into this problem as well.

In the Zend_Date class 'YYYY' means to a 4 digit representation of the 'ISO year' where as 'yyyy' means a 4 digit representation of the 'year'.

Comment: Yeah...I don't really know what ISO year means, so I assumed they were pretty much the same.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure either so I'll just present a wikipeida page: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date